# Displaying Channel Form based on member group, number of entries/channel within a date range

Tags: safecracker, members, conditionals

I am trying to run a conditional which displays a "can't post" message if the member of a group_id 1 had previously posted 2 entries in a channel. Otherwise, it displays a channel form to post an entry.

If the member belongs to group_id 2, he/she can't post more than 5 entries. Less than 5 entries, displays the channel form.

```
{if logged_in}
{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{logged_in_member_id}"}

{exp:channel:entries
    channel="news"
    author_id="CURRENT_USER"
    dynamic="no"
    start_on="-1 months"
    stop_before="now"
    disable="pagination"
    status="not closed"
    parse="inward"
}
{if logged_in_group_id == 1}
    {if absolute_count < 2 }
{if:else}
    {if absolute_count < 5 }
{/if}
        Display the channel form
    {if:else}
        Throw an error message!
    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
{/if}
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your conditional logic is awry.  Try something like:

```
{if logged_in}
{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{logged_in_member_id}"}

    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="news"
        author_id="CURRENT_USER"
        dynamic="no"
        start_on="-1 months"
        stop_before="now"
        disable="pagination"
        status="not closed"
        parse="inward"
    }
    {if 
        (logged_in_group_id == 1 && absolute_count < 2) ||
        (logged_in_group_id == 2 && absolute_count < 5) ||
        no_results
    }
            Display the channel form
    {if:else}
            Throw an error message!
    {/if}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
    {/if}
```

HTH

Comment: The absolute count was creating a problem. Had to use stash and set a variable with scope=local and then call it instead of absolute_count. It worked dandy!

Comment: There seems to be a problem if there are no results. Need to display the form, if the member hasn't posted any entry.

Comment: You just need to add a conditional to test for that - EE sets a variable called no_results if a channel:entries call produces nothing.  I've amended the example -

Comment: The {if no_results} {/if} conditional outputs raw data of anything which is enclosed in it. A redirect did not help. However, an embed tag inside it, did help. {if no_results}{embed='forms/_post_news'}{/if}, where _post_news is the form template.

Comment: OK - glad you got it sorted :)